# Two foreign keys in a table referencing one primary key in another table using rails migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, rubygems, relational-database

Im trying to create a table with 2 FK Referencing 1 PK in another table.

```
class CreateJobapps < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :jobapps do |t|
      t.references :job, foreign_key: { job: :id }, index: { unique: true}
      t.references :user, foreign_key: { user: :id }, index: { unique: true}
      t.timestamps


    end
  end
end
```

Is this method correct? if so, how can I get an output if I provide a FK of respected table.

Here is how my Jobapp table looks like

[image]

I tried using `Jobapp.joins(:user)`  but to no avail
Am I supposed to write belongs_to or has_many in the model file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class CreateJobapps < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :jobapps do |t|
      t.references :job, foreign_key: { job: :id }
      t.references :user, foreign_key: { user: :id }
      t.timestamps
    end
    # Add a compound index instead - you may need to switch the order to
    # tweak the index depending on how it is used.
    add_index :jobapps, [:job_id, :user_id], unique: true 
  end
end
```

```
class Jobapp < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :job
end
```

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :jobapps
  has_many :jobs, through: :jobapps
end
```

```
class Job < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :jobapps
  has_many :users, through: :jobapps
end
```

Comment: The name jobapps is just weird though.

Comment: If id like to do a GET api request from Jobapp, such as print all, but print all the stuff in the Job table as well. Since Jobapps has only ids, it wont print any information. How is that possible? Is it by making use of the FK to PK of table jobs which has all the info?

Comment: `@jobapps = JobApp.includes(:job).all; @jobapps.each { |j| puts j.job.name  }`

Comment: If you really want to do a plain join instead of loading the associated model you need to select the rows from jobs `@jobapps = JobApp.joins(:job).select('jobapps.*', 'jobs.name AS job_name'); @jobapps.each { |j| puts j.job_name }`

Comment: I've tried  ```jobapps = Jobapp.joins(:job).select('jobapps.*', 'job.title AS job_title'); jobapps.each { |j| puts j.title }``` but I'm getting this error ```PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table \"job\"\nLINE 1: SELECT jobapps.*, job.title AS job_stitle FROM \"jobapps\" INN...\n                          ^\n: SELECT jobapps.*, job.title AS job_stitle FROM \"jobapps\" INNER JOIN \"jobs\" ON \"jobs\".\"id\" = \"jobapps\".\"job_id\">",```

Comment: That's because the table is named `jobs` and not `job`. `'jobs.title AS job_title'`.

Comment: Ye I've tried that but I got this instead, so im not sure ```undefined method `title' for #<Jobapp:0x601b480>>",```

Comment: Dude. Read that code again. You're selecting 'jobs.title AS job_title'. enough follow up questions.

Comment: I've managed to get it working, had an extra line of code that affected it which got me confused. Thanks a lot for the help though. appreciate it!